# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression in Chrome, FF and IE fine

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

This line of code:

```
if ( new RegExp("\\b" + arrCategorySort[i]+ "\\b", "g").test(titleText) )
{
    catFound = true;
}
```

works perfect in Firefox (6.0), and in IE (7.0), but not in Chrome (13.0.782.112)

do you have any idea why?

Comment: What's in `arrCategorySort[i]`?

Comment: in arrCategorySort[i] there is one word (or maybe even more words) - (it's a loop through these items: var arrCategorySort = new Array ("menu", "food", "drink", "drinks", "2 course", "three course");  Could it be the error appears when two words are in?

Comment: Those that you listed should work fine, however some combinations may be invalid (with all sorts of braces and brackets, backslashes etc.). IE and FF may handle invalid regexes in a different way than Chrome.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a try/catch around your code and display the value that is causing the exception :

```
try {
    if ( new RegExp("\\b" + arrCategorySort[i]+ "\\b", "g").test(titleText) )
        catFound = true;
}
catch (e) {
    confirm (e + ' : at index ' + i + ', category is "' + arrCategorySort[i] + '"');  
}
```

Comment: I get this error msg: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\bfunction (a,b){var c=b||window,d=[];for(var e=0,f=this.length;e<f;++e){if(!a.call(c,this[e],e,this))continue;d.push(this[e])‌​}return d}\b/: Nothing to repeat : at index filter, category is "function (a,b){var c=b||window,d=[];for(var e=0,f=this.length;e<f;++e){if(!a.call(c,this[e],e,this))continue;d.push(this[e])‌​}return d}" But, now the sorting works! (if i ignore the error msg in the catch block)

Comment: I works because the catch is effectively ignoring the error so the rest of your code is executing. The error appears to be to be that you are passing a function in as arrCategerySort[i]. We need to know how the index i is being generated. Please provide the source of the loop iterating i.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `arrCategorySort[i]` as a string contains special characters as far as the RegExp parser is concerned (e.g. `{}` and `[]`). With your string in place, you're trying to parse regexp

```
 /\bfunction (a,b){var c=b||window,d=[];for(var e=0,f=this.length;e<f;++e){if(!a.call(c,this[e],e,this))continue;d.push(this[e])‌​}return d}\b/
```

After your `(a,b)` in the beginning, in `{}` you have `var ...` however `{}` mean repeated pattern and expect to have a number between them (or two numbers).  What you really need is to escape all special chars: `{}[]|()\,.*+` - by prepending '\' character in front of each of them. (There may be a couple more, escapes me at the moment.)

Comment: But the problem is I only have those simple strings in arrCategorySort[i]. And as I said in the comment above, when I added the try catch block, it works now :?

Comment: Just use search/replace for those to escape it.  I don't know anything about the rest of your code/project so can't say what works/doesn't work.  My best guess is that it doesn't work in other browsers either - but they don't throw an error.